# Total of two vallues - with one as nonzero - returning zero

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Following `Action Method` is returning `Total` as `0` even though some of the values `item1_price,, item9_price`, etc. are non-zeros. The `View` also displays the item values correctly (i.e. 0.00 or 15.45 etc.) but the `Total` is displayed as `0.

**Question**: How can we make total work here correctly?

```
public class CustomerOrdersModelView
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int FY { get; set; }

    public float? item1_price { get; set; }
    public float? item2_price { get; set; }
    ...
    public float? item9_price { get; set; }

    public float? Total { get; set; }
}
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductAnnualReport(string rpt)
{
    var qry = from c in _context.Customers
              join ord in _context.Orders
                on c.CustomerID equals ord.CustomerID into co
              from m in co.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new CustomerOrdersModelView
              {
                  CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                  FY = c.FY,
                  price = co.item1_price ?? 0,
                  price = co.item2_price ?? 0,
                  ...
                  price = co.item9_price ?? 0,

                  Total = co.item1_price ?? 0 + co.item2_price ?? 0 + ....+ co.item9_price ?? 0
              };
 }
```

**View:**

```
<tr>
     <td>Item1:</td>
     <td>@Model.item1_price</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Item2:</td>
     <td>@Model.item2_price</td>
</tr>
...
<tr>
     <td>Item9:</td>
     <td>@Model.item9_price</td>
</tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL:</td>
            <td>@Model.Total</td>
        </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: The first term in the expression that isn't null is zero. The operator precedence isn't what you assumed it would be. Add parentheses to disambiguate that expression.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Adding parentheses around `co.item1_price ?? 0 + co.item2_price ?? 0 + ....+ co.item9_price ?? 0` still returns zero. How can I test it in controller? - because when I put a breakpoint on last line of the action method  `Total = co.item1_price ?? 0 + ......` it places the breakpoint on the entire select statement starting from` new CustomerOrdersModelView{.....`

Comment: I can't help but notice that *you're not telling me where you added them*. I may have expressed myself poorly, though: Add parens to indicate what you mean by it.

Comment: What Ed meant was: `Total = (co.item1_price ?? 0) + (co.item2_price ?? 0) + (....) + (co.item9_price ?? 0)`. Now if any of these have a value, then your `Total` will have a value.

Comment: @EdPlunkett After your suggestion, in action method on the last line, I now have `Total = (co.item1_price ?? 0 + co.item2_price ?? 0 + ....+ co.item9_price ?? 0)`

Comment: Well, you can't expect parens around the outside of the whole expression to have much impact on how the compiler parses what's inside the parens.

Comment: @Silvermind Thank you for pointing out what `@EdPlunkett` meant in his first comment. it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float? item1_price = 0;
float? item2_price = 1;
float? item3_price = 2;

float f = item1_price ?? 0 + item2_price ?? 0 + item3_price ?? 0;
```

`f` is equal to `0`, because this is how the expression is parsed, due to operator precedence and associativity:

```
float f = item1_price ?? ((0 + item2_price) ?? ((0 + item3_price) ?? 0));
```

But this is what you meant:

```
float f = (item1_price ?? 0) + (item2_price ?? 0) + (item3_price ?? 0);
```

Always parenthesize complicated expressions.

See [Section 14.2.1 of the ECMA C# Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) for the operator precedence table (thanks @Silvermind and Eric). Order of precedence is from highest to lowest: `*` comes above `+`, so `1 * 2 + 3` is parsed as `(1 * 2) + 3`.

```
Primary           x.y f(x) a[x] x++ x-- 
                  new typeof checked unchecked

Unary             + - ! ~ ++x --x (T)x
Multiplicative    * / %
Additive          + -
Shift             << >>

Relational &      < > <= >= is as
type-testing

Equality          == !=
Logical           AND &
Logical           XOR ^
Logical           OR |
Conditional       AND &&
Conditional       OR ||
Null Coalescing   ??
Conditional       ?:

Assignment        = *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= 
                  &= ^= |=
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett It works now (thank you). Sorry, I misunderstood your first comment

Comment: @nam No prob, my comment could have used some disambiguation itself.

Comment: The relevant line of the specification is not that the operation is right-associative. If it were left associative then the parenthesization would be `((i1 ?? (0 + i2)) ?? (0 + i3)) ?? 0`, which is still wrong. The relevant line of the spec is the operator precedence table, which indicates that `+` is higher precedence than `??`. (Exercise: can you create a program which has different results depending on whether `??` is left or right associative?)

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you. Once again.